# How to add isort, epylint, pylint, pyreverse, and symilar to PATH in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, pylint

I installed pylint in VSCODE but then I got this warning

```
WARNING: The script isort is installed in '/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts epylint, pylint, pyreverse and symilar are installed in '/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you